# cambiar el contenido de un input con jquery o javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Deseo cambiar el valor escrito en 55 `inputs` que tienen la misma clase llamada `input_valores_provisionales` y distinto id (1,2,3,4...) en una función apenas se cargue la pagina

---

aqui el script

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  document.getElementsByClassName("input_valores_provisionales").value="0";

    $(".input_valores_provisionales").attr("value","0");//linea que no funciona

//cada vez que el usuario oprime una tecla en cualquiera de los input
  $('.input_valores_provisionales').keyup(
    function()
    {
      var total = 0;
      //recorremos los input para que haga la suma
      $(".input_valores_provisionales").each(
        function()
        {
          //compruebo que lo digitado sea un numero
          if (!isNaN($(this).val()))
          {
            //convierto a entero la cadena del input en base 10
            var numero_entero = parseInt($(this).val(),10);
            total = total+numero_entero;
            //muestro la suma en el span
            $("#total_provisionales").text(total);
          }
          else
          {
              alert("Debe ingresar un valor numerico");
              $(this).val('0');
          }
        }
      );
    }
  );
});
```

he intentado de las siguientes formas y tampoco funciona

```
 $('.input_valores_provisionales > input').val("0");
    $(".input_valores_provisionales").text("0");
    document.getElementsByClassName("input_valores_provisionales").value="0";
```

no obstante esta forma si funciona, y de una vez compruebo que la clase si esta bien escrita si no esto no haría efecto

```
$(".input_valores_provisionales").attr("placeholder","0");
```

pero no me sirve por que el cero no lo toma como valor numérico, es mas bien 'un cero fantasma' que se muestra ahí y desaparece al poner el cursor sobre el input, según esto el problema para mi, no esta en que el jquery no haga su función respectiva si no que pareciera que el input estuviera "bloqueado" para escribir en el mediante jquery o javascript, con el teclado puedo escribir normalmente

he intentado poner el atributo `value="0"` a cada uno de los 55 inputs y tampoco funcion

he intentado quitarle y agregarle el atributo `type="text"` y tampoco

¿Alguna idea de que puede ser?

Comment: ¿Probaste con `$(".input_valores_provisionales").attr("value","0");`? De pronto hay otra tarea corriendo en tu script que impide que se pueda asignar por JS o JQ el value...

Comment: Y puedes producir un [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Si replico tu código, funciona (no es necesario incluir los id para esta demostración):

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('.input_valores_provisionales').val("10"); // sí funciona

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input_valores_provisionales">
<input type="text" class="input_valores_provisionales">
<input type="text" class="input_valores_provisionales">
<input type="text" class="input_valores_provisionales">
```